# referencing mySQL query components

Tags: mysql, sql, select, alias

Is there a way to make reference to parts of a MySQL query within the same query?

For example:

```
SELECT 50000 AS starting_principle, .065*50000 AS interest, 
    principle + interest AS principle_plus_interest
```

The third column, `principle_plus_interest` in the query set gives me an error.  Is there a way to code this besides writing `50000 + .065*50000 AS principle_plus_interest`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot refer to aliases in the `select` list (or the `where` clause, for that matter). One way around this is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT starting_principle, 
       interest, 
       principle + interest AS principle_plus_interest 
FROM   (SELECT 50000 AS starting_principle, .065*50000 AS interest
        FROM   some_table) t
```

Comment: doing `50000 + .065*50000 AS principle_plus_interest` would be a much better solution than an inline view though.

Comment: Actually, I think `select 50000 as starting_principle, 0.065 as interest` should be in the subquery.  Then the calculation should be based on these items.